# How to animate update position of CAReplicatorLayer in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-animation, calayer

I need to animate my CAReplicatorLayer object for 50 pixels up.

I achieved update a CAReplicatorLayer frame to 50 pixels up but i didn't achieve with animation.

Here is my code.

```
 CATransaction.begin();
 CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
 self.rippleLayer.position = self.imgLogo.center //rippleLayer is my CAReplicatorLayer object and self.imgLogo.center is like 50 pixels up for refernce.
 CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
 CATransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Well `setDisableActions(true)` means “do not animate”. So you do not animate.

Comment: @matt, If i remove setDisableActions then my application got crashed

Answer (score 1):

My code proves that your code has no problem. If it crashed, there must be some other reasons.

```
var rippleLayer: CAReplicatorLayer!
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    rippleLayer = CAReplicatorLayer.init()
    rippleLayer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    rippleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(rippleLayer)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { _ in
        CATransaction.begin();
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
        self.rippleLayer.position = self.view.center //rippleLayer is my CAReplicatorLayer object and self.imgLogo.center is like 50 pixels up for refernce.
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        CATransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: By mistake, init layer method was commented thats why crash is raised and now it solved.